# JIRA XRAY plugin creates duplicate test case when importing using API and feature file

Tags: bash, cucumber, jira, bdd, jira-xray

I have a bash script that takes all the feature files from a specific directory and uses `/rest/raven/1.0/import/feature?projectKey=XYZ` XRAY-JIRA API to create TEST CASES in JIRA.

`XRAY version 4.2.1_j7`

I am running this script in a JENKINS-PIPELINE but the problem is when I run it for the first time it creates test cases which are correct but when I re-run the build it starts creating the same test cases again (duplicating them), any suggestion / reason why this is happening

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find <DIR_PATH> -type f -name "*.feature" | while read fname;
do
 curl -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" -X $USERNAME:$PASSWORD -F "file=@$fname" 
 https://<JIRA_URL>/rest/raven/1.0/import/feature?projectKey=XYZ
done
```

Sample feature file:

```
Feature Facebook Login
 
 @Login
 Scenario: Log in to FB app
  Given: User is at FB login page
  When User enters username and password
  Then User is logged in successfully
```

Please suggest me how and where can I debug to fix the issue
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would highly recommend you to upgrade to the latest version is your current version is "rather old". Version 6.0 was just released few days ago.
I don't any open bug related to that, except [this bug](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-4449) that been solved many releases ago.
You can try importing using a zip file, in a single request (which is  more efficient btw). Maybe this approach implicitly addresses your problem, in the version in that you have.

Example:

```
rm -f features.zip
zip -r features.zip src/test/resources/calculator/ -i \*.feature
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -u admin:admin -F "file=@features.zip" "http://192.168.56.102/rest/raven/1.0/import/feature?projectKey=CALC"
```

If the problem persists, then mostly there's a bug there; please [reach out Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2), so the team can properly analyze it with you.

Comment: Ok, let me try to update the plugin. I tried with the zip file but still same

Comment: Then I think it's best to either update the app or reach Xray support

Comment: By curiosity, were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi,
Yes with the latest XRAY plugin everything works as expected. I tested it today and with my automation, all tests are created only one time in JIRA (mo duplication)